# Where can I download Microsoft VC80.CRT version 8.0.50608.0?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, microsoft-word, troubleshooting

I've just installed **Microsoft Office Home and Student 2007** in **Windows XP SP3**

When trying to run MS word or any other office app (Excel, PowerPoint), I get the following message: **this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect**

This also happens with other applications, for instance, Acrobat Reader.

A bit of Googling around this error message suggests that this might be due to a mismatch of library versions. In fact, most of the articles and [forum messages](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/36971526-95f3-4a9f-a601-1843c86332c1) I found mention a programmer writing an application in Visual C++ and sending it to someone else, who then runs into that error. This is hardly my case !

I looked into Office's files and the [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375365) for Excel suggests that Office is trying to use Microsoft VC80.CRT version *8.0.50608.0*. However, in my Windows System folder, I can only find the assemblies for *8.0.50727.762*

My next step will be trying to find version 8.0.50608.0. How can I find and download it ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it appears Microsoft has provided the 8.0.50727.42 installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387). No luck so far in finding a download for 8.0.50608.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) 8.0.50608.0 from <http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en>

Answer (score 0):

this is the actual download for 8.0.50608.0.     The above post is for SP1 which is 8.0.50727.762.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3387
(Link is no longer valid as of 06/2021)