# restore content of Windows Manifest file

Tags: windows-7, file-corruption

On my Windows 7 there's the file `C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_0c178a139ee2a7ed.manifest`. This file is corrupt, i.e. it doesn't contain the data it should, as is clearly visible from it's content as well as from the log file generated by `sfc /scannow`.

Can someone please post the content of this file somewhere or tell me where to get it?

---

More information:

The relevant part of the log file created by `sfc /scannow` is this:

```
2015-10-07 12:39:29, Error                 CSI    00000208 (F) Unable to load manifest for component [ml:280{140},l:150{75}]"x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_0c178a139ee2a7ed"[gle=0x80004005]
2015-10-07 12:39:29, Error                 CSI    00000209@2015/10/7:10:39:29.214 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\componentstore\storelayout.cpp(2714): Store corruption detected in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::FetchManifestContent expression: 0
  FileHashMismatch on resource [102]"\winsxs\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_0c178a139ee2a7ed.manifest"[gle=0x80004005]
```

I'm using Windows 7 Home Professional 32 bit with Service Pack 1.

I already tried to extract the needed file from a Windows 7 installation disc, but the disc doesn't contain that file.
Also, the Windows 7 (exactly the same version as mentioned above) I installed in VirtualBox doesn't contain the needed file.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried booting the Windows install disk, entering repair, and executing `sfc /scannow` from it's command prompt? This worked for me a while back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc

That's referring to the 32-bit Visual C++ v8.0 Microsoft Foundation Classes, (version 8.0.50727.762 specifically), which are added when you install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86).

So, uninstall any existing Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable packages, and reinstall (the SP1, 32-bit version) [from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638)

This existing SU question has some more/related info and download links:

[Where can I download Microsoft VC80.CRT version 8.0.50608.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/210608/where-can-i-download-microsoft-vc80-crt-version-8-0-50608-0)

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! I posted the files content [in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2dcd3b0d799334084a5), in case anyone else has the same problem.